# Updating Winforms UI in real time while waiting for a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous, system.reactive

The below code does not work in 'real time'. The intention is, when the button is clicked, validate a set of data on the background thread. I cannot allow true 'submission' until all of the data is validated, but I do want the textbox to update in real time.

Instead, the textbox gets updated with the odd numbers, all at once.

I imagine what is happening is that the task.Wait is blocking the observable since I am observing on the main thread, but I cannot see a way around this as I need to update on the main thread.

(Obviously this is just a proof of concept)

Somewhat related note - is this code guaranteed to threadsafe? Thanks.

```
private Subject<int> _subject; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int sleep = 2000;
    private int i = 0;
    private void LongRunningValidation(int num)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0) return;

        Thread.Sleep(sleep * (i++));

        _subject.OnNext(num);
    }


    private ConcurrentBag<int> _bag;
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _subject = new Subject<int>();
        _subject.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Synchronize().Subscribe(UpdateTextBox);

        _bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        if(Validate())
        {
            //submit
        }
    }

    private bool Validate()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(StartValidationAsync);

        task.Wait();

        return true;
    }

    private void StartValidationAsync()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_bag, LongRunningValidation);
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(int i)
    {
        textEdit1.Text = textEdit1.Text + "," + i;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Validate`  method not async and as you say block main thread. Try use events:

```
public delegate void ValidatedHandler(bool validate);
public event ValidatedHandler Validated;

private void Validate()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(StartValidationAsync);

        if (Validated != null)
           Validated(true);
    }
```

And subscribe on event:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _subject = new Subject<int>();
     _subject.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Synchronize().Subscribe(UpdateTextBox);

_bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

this.Validated += OnValidated;
}


public void OnValidated(bool validate)
{
        if(validate)
        {
            //submit
        }
}
```

Comment: I actually just realized I should just use Task.ContinueWith and then 'submit', but this is I guess the same idea. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms does not automatically update the UI, even if you are running a background thread. Try calling Update() on whatever you want to update.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue. The underlying issue is that the UpdateTextBox method will not get called until the task (i.e. the parallel foreach on the background thread) is completed, since the Wait blocks the UI Thread.